# Nodejs, DTO, input types and return types of methods

Tags: node.js, dto

How can I get as close as possible to 3 following features in nodejs?

```
// 1./ namespaces for types, so I don't need to have long type names
import foo.bar.Type1;
import foo.bar.Type2;
...

// 2./ strict complex types of method parameters
// 3./ strict complex type for return type
public function foo(Type1 param1, Type2 param2): Type3 {
    ...
}
```

It is all about ability to introduce DTO in our project, which is becoming really mess without it :(.

What is the nodejs industry standard for dealing with DTOs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Nesting your JS files in directories is about as close as you can get to namespaces.

If you have a directory structure like

```
foo >
    bar >
        Type1.js
        Type2.js
```

Then it can be imported with:

```
const Type1 = require('./foo/bar/Type1');
const Type2 = require('./foo/bar/Type2');
```

2. Node is a loosely-typed language, so if you really need strict typing across the board then you should probably look at other language options. If you just need it in specific situations though, you can use the `typeof` operator to determine types passed into functions and reject calls that don't satisfy the type requirements.

Example:

```
function test(someString, someNum, someObject) {
    if ( typeof someString != 'string' ||
         typeof someNum != 'number' ||
         typeof someObject != 'object' )
    { return false; }

    // Execute function
    return true;
}
```

3. There's no native way in Node to enforce a return type for a particular function (again, if you explicitly need this behavior then you might want to consider a strictly-typed language). There are "linting" tools out there though which you can use to define typing for return values (and for arguments too, so this also applies to question 2). These tools can be set up to run alongside tests for a project and they will reject functions which do not satisfy specified return values. [ESLint](https://eslint.org) is a popular option for this. This should not be confused with native functionality, as it requires you to include special formatted comments above every function in order to work.

Comment: Thank You for answer! I will definitelly check ESlint. For static analysis and types enforcing I'll at the end probably use either TypeScript or Flow.